# Generate x characters worth of Lorem Ipsum text (sentences and paragraphs)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, faker

I have a User field called 'bio' that can be up to 800 characters (as well as some other free text fields of varying lengths). Having it populate with dummy text would help assess the visuals/design of the front end.

How can I generate 800 characters worth of Lorem Ipsum text to place into that field? By 'Lorem Ipsum text' I mean sentences and paragraphs (not just 800 characters worth of sentences in one giant paragraph).

`"a"*800` is not varied enough to resemble human paragraphs.

Note: this is for the `seeds.rb` file, and I am already using `faker` gem, in case that's useful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are better ways, but this uses the `Faker` gem and looks quite natural:

```rb
def make_natural_text(n)
  paras = ""
  until paras.length > n
    para = Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(number: (2..7).to_a.sample(1)[0]).join + "\n\n"
    paras += para 
  end
  paras[0..(n-1)]
end


natural_text = make_natural_text(800)

puts natural_text
```